# Newtonian 2-Body problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, general-relativity, post-newtonian

The Newtonian equations of motion for two-point masses $m$ and $m^{\prime}$ are derived from the following Lagrangian:

$$L = \frac{1}{2}m\mathbf{v}^{2} + \frac{1}{2}m^{\prime}\mathbf{v}^{\prime \, 2} + \frac{Gmm^{\prime}}{R} \, ,$$
where $R = |r - r^{\prime}|$. In Damour, T.; Deruelle, N. (1985), [“General relativistic celestial mechanics of binary systems. I. The post-Newtonian motion”](https://eudml.org/doc/76291), it's stated the center-of-mass integral is:

$$\mathbf{K} = m \mathbf{r} + m^{\prime} \mathbf{r}^{\prime} - t \mathbf{P}_{N} \, .$$ Where does the term $t\mathbf{P}_{N}$ come from?

Comment: The title of the paper explicitly told you that it is going to handle GR corrections. It is post-Newtonian. Have you learnt about that?

Comment: I didn't learn it, I don't know where $K_n$ comes from. Incidentally, isn't this a classical problem? I can only assume it might come from Galilean transformations.

Comment: Look, the title already told you that they are interested in General Relativity. Why do you think Galilean transformations would be relevant?

Comment: *Where does the term $t\mathbf P_N$ come from?* Isn’t it just due to the uniform motion of the center of mass?